# How to set textfield value in JSP action

Tags: forms, jsp

I am designing a JSP page with form action.

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  Username: <input type="textfield" name="username" /> 
  Country : <input type="textfield" name="country" /> 
  Url : <input type="textfield" name="Url" />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I want to set the user given URL value in form action when I click the *Submit* button and redirect to that URL. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is quite similar, i guess
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651187/i-want-to-set-the-jsp-text-field-values-in-struts2-action-class-automatically-wh

Comment: I guess you want to redirect **after** the values were submitted to your server, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can work pretty well

```
<form action="" method="post" id="myForm">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" />
    Country : <input type="text" name="country" />
    Url : <input id="url" type="text" name="Url" />

    <button onclick="doStuff();">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    function doStuff(){
        $('#myForm').attr('action', $('#url').val());
        $('#myForm').submit();
    }
</script>
```

Don't forget to include the JQuery api's in your code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```